# Publish InfoPath form in SharePoint 2013 not working

Tags: infopath, form

I have full permission on the SharePoint 2013 server: I can create a form library, I can edit the form library in SharePoint Designer 2013, but in InfoPath 2013 I can't.

In addition I can't create form libraries from InfoPath, it gives me an error but it is not clear what the problem is.

The error I get:

> InfoPath cannot save the following form... This libary was either renamed or deleted, or network problems are preventing the file from being saved

Comment: I think its not configured properly, can you double check by following this article: http://www.appvity.com/blogs/post/2013/06/16/How-to-configure-and-publish-InfoPath-to-SharePoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was that I was using a windows 2008 server and hasn't the desktop experience enabled, it seems that this enables webdav or so.

Comment: You are correct.  Server 2008+ requires Desktop Experience to enable WebDav. MS has a reference section on MSDN on protocols used for SharePoint:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc339473(v=office.12).aspx -- If you look at [MS-IPFF2] - you will see it does indeed use the WebDav protocol.  You could also use a tool like Fiddler to see the protocol requests.